# How to precompile JSP on WildFly (with ANT)?

Tags: jsp, ant, wildfly

I'm migrating an old application that uses JSP and is built with Ant from Weblogic to WildFly. Normal JSP compilation "on the fly" for development mode works fine. However, when building a production deployment, the script precompiles all JSP files, which is useful not only for performance, but also as an automated check for some errors.

For Weblogic it was this:

```
<java classname="weblogic.jspc"
      fork="yes">
  ...
</java>
```

But how do I do that for WildFly? Googling gave no result.

Comment: If WildFly uses jasper for compiling JSP pages, you should be able to following the instructions for precompiling JSPs from the [Tomcat documentation](https://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-7.0-doc/jasper-howto.html)

Comment: There are so many things dependent on Tomcat though. Like `<import file="${tomcat.home}/bin/catalina-tasks.xml"/>` and so on.

Comment: I do not do it that way.  I do `<taskdef classname="org.apache.jasper.JspC" name="jasper2"><classpath refid="jspc.class.path"/></taskdef>` to define the `jasper2` task which I use later.  The refid `jspc.class.path` is to a `<path>` declaration that includes all the jars/paths needed for jasper.  Note, I am using tomcat, so I have not directly tested jasper usage for other servlet containers.